# keyframe animation not playing after clicking link

Tags: html, css

I have a full screen drop down menu that goes up and down the screen when the user interacts with the menu button. I didn't like that the full screen menu animates when the page loads so I set the opacity of the menu to 0 so that you wouldn't see the animation when the page loads. I created an `onclick` event that sets the opacity to 1 when the user clicks on the menu. that solved the issue of seeing the animation when the user loads the index page. here's the code for how I did it:

HTML

```
<div class="menu">
    <input type="checkbox" class="toggler" onclick="document.getElementById('overlay').style.opacity='1'">

    <div class="icon">
        <div></div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="overlay" id="overlay">

        <nav>
            <div id="nav-links"></div>
        </nav>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
@keyframes slideDown {
0% {
    transform: translateY(-100%)
    }

100% {
    transform: translateY(0%)
    }
}

@keyframes slideUp {
0% {
    transform: translateY(0%)
    }

100% {
    transform: translateY(-100%);
    }
}

.overlay {
position: fixed;
background: var(--taupe-color);
opacity: 0;
top: 0;
left: 0;
width: 100vw;
height: 100vh;
display: flex;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;
text-align: center;
}

.menu .toggler:checked ~ .overlay {
animation: slideDown 2s forwards;
}

.menu .toggler:not(:checked) ~ .overlay {
animation: slideUp 2s forwards;
}
```

The only issue now is that when the user clicks on a link to navigate to another page from the menu, the menu no longer animates up. My guess is that on page load, the opacity over the overlay menu is set back to 0 so we can't see the animation actually happening on the other pages. My only idea to fix this is to duplicate the overlay class for the other pages and give it a different name but set the opacity to 1. I'm wondering if there is a better solution than the one I came up with. Ideally, the animation only happens when a link is clicked in the menu or when the menu button is toggled.

EDIT
is there a way to have the menu animate only when the user clicks the menu button or clicks one of the nav links in the menu?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest maybe adding a class to turn the opacity to 1 upon clicking?

I'm not sure if this is what you are looking for, but here is Codepen that I believe does what you're looking for:

```css
@keyframes slideDown {
0% {
    transform: translateY(-100%)
    }

100% {
    transform: translateY(0%)
    }
}

@keyframes slideUp {
0% {
    transform: translateY(0%)
    }

100% {
    transform: translateY(-100%);
    }
}

.overlay {
position: fixed;
background: var(--taupe-color);
opacity: 0;
top: 0;
left: 0;
width: 100vw;
height: 100vh;
display: flex;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;
text-align: center;
}

.active {
  opacity:1;
}

.menu .toggler:checked ~ .overlay {
animation: slideDown 2s forwards;
}

.menu .toggler:not(:checked) ~ .overlay {
animation: slideUp 2s forwards;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
    <input type="checkbox" class="toggler" onclick="document.getElementById('overlay').classList.add('active')">

    <div class="icon">
        <div></div>
    </div>
  
    
    <div class="overlay" id="overlay">

        <nav>
            <div id="nav-links"></div>
          TESTTTTTTTTTTTT
        </nav>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I just gave it a shot and it results in the same issue. the index page loads correctly because I don't have to watch the animation when the page initially loads. but when the user toggles the menu and clicks on the link, the menu should animate back up the page and then load the next page.

Comment: Essentially what I am trying to achieve is this:

User visits webpage (menu animation does not open and close)
User clicks on menu (menu slides down page)
User clicks on link (menu slides up page and loads the next page)

Comment: Personally, I would maybe try with creating two classes, one where the animation is slideDown and another where it is slideUp, and upon clicking on the menu, then it slides down (which at least in my codepen seems to be happening that way), and when clicking on the menu, then add the class with the slideUp animation for it to go back up and proceed with the relevant code).
I'm on mobile now, but will try later to test it out too :)

Comment: I ended up doing two classes and also duplicating the index page and calling the duplicate home. when the user loads the index page, they don't have to watch the menu animation on page load but all the links point to the "home" html which allows the menu to operate as normal. not the best solution but it's working for now